# Not printing nested serialiser in Django Rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class PolicyPortalUser2020(User):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    fname=models.TextField()
    lname=models.TextField()
    mobile_no=models.TextField()


class Mentor2020(models.Model):
    pUser = models.ForeignKey(PolicyPortalUser2020, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 40, null = True, blank = True)
    state = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.pUser.fname + ' ' + self.pUser.lname

    def full_name(self):
        return  self.pUser.fname + ' ' + self.pUser.lname
```

serializers.py

```
class PolicyPortalUser2020Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PolicyPortalUser2020
        fields = ['id', 'fname', 'lname']


class Mentor2020Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = PolicyPortalUser2020Serializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor2020
        fields = ['id', 'state', 'user']
```

output

```
[
    {
        "id": 27,
        "state": "asdasdas"
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "state": "12121"
    },
    {
        "id": 29,
        "state": "12121"
    },
    {
        "id": 30,
        "state": "12121"
    },
    {
        "id": 26,
        "state": "asdasdas"
    }
]
```

Basically I am using nested serialiser in one of my project but I don't know why it is not giving me the desired output, There is no nested field I get as an output.

Please help me to tackle this problem

Comment: Try to change `user` to `pUser` in `Mentor2020Serializer`.

Comment: Or add `source='pUser'` in `user = PolicyPortalUser2020Serializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='pUser')`

Comment: bro i am getting this error - 'TypeError: 'PolicyPortalUser2020' object is not iterable
'

Comment: What change has you made?

Comment: I tried both of these

Comment: Remove `many=True`. If it does not work the write here part of the stacktrace

Comment: no error but getting same output